# Cortana error "I'm sorry, but I can't speak your language" in Canada

Tags: 8.1, cortana

My phone's OS version is 8.10.14203.306.

According to Microsoft's document http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/cortana/cortana-alpha how to enable Cortana in Canada I need to set 3 things:

**Language**
[image]

**Region**
[image]

**Speech**
[image]

After I have all these settings, when I run Cortana I get an error message saying "I'm sorry, but I can't speak your language". Is there anything wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the help page you need the OS version 8.10.14214.329 or above. Yours seems a bit lower. Check if there are any additional updates available for the dev preview.

Comment: Great observation!

Comment: My latest stable update is what I have now, I will think about if I will go and install the review or not.

Comment: That explains it - I think Canadian is (like German and some other languages) only availiable in the Dev preview.

Comment: Originally, you had to have the Dev Preview, but that requirement was dropped last fall sometime. I'm in Canada with Rogers and Cortana works here. My info is: OS version 8.10.14234.375, Language is English (Canada), Region is Canada and Regional Format is set to: match phone language and Speech is set to US. If I remember correctly, you had the Windows 8.1 Update for it to work. Not sure what version that is, though.

Answer (score 1):

In language setting keep US at the top
In region setting keep US as your region and Country.

Basically set at fields to US and Turn On "Location", and you will be good to go.
It worked for me, even though I am in India.

Comment: I confirm that Cortana only works when the region is set to United States regardless of language settings as of OS version 8.10.14219.341. The error message “I'm sorry, but I can't speak your language” is completely misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Set region to United States keep language setting as you want, will work in Canada.