# Cortanta still not work in Canada with latest Developer Preview

Tags: cortana, 8.1-update-1, developer-preview

This is actually a follow up question to [Cortana error "I'm sorry, but I can't speak your language" in Canada](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/cortana-error-im-sorry-but-i-cant-speak-your-language-in-canada)

I am following Microsoft's document http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/cortana/cortana-alpha and installed latest Preview for Developers. I think I have met all requirements.

## OS Version

[image]

It is later than 8.10.14214.329 as needed.

## Language Setting

[image]

English Canada is the first one in list.

## Region

[image]
Canada is my region.

## Speech

[image]
English US is the speech as required.

With all the settings when I run Cortata I still got error message `I'm sorry, but I can't speak your language`.

Any clue?

Comment: Please add the new information to your existing question instead of posting what's essentially a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that the English (Canada) language package was removed by manufacturer. See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wpdp-wpcortana/cortanta-still-not-work-in-canada-with-latest/d7036ea8-e459-409d-9ac5-92a608d32dc6 for details.